# Center with respect to the parent, but without overlapping siblings

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a fixed width and three children, the first child should be left aligned and with width auto, and the third child should be right aligned and with width auto.

For the middle child (which is just some text), I would like it to be centered with respect to the container (if there is enough space), no matter what the size of the other two children are, but I also want it to follow `text-overflow: ellipsis` if there isn’t enough space.

If you look at the code below:

- The first option has "Some text" correctly centered, but if you resize the container it will overlap with the buttons on the sides.
- The second option behaves correctly with respect to `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but is centered with respect to the empty space, not with respect to the outer container.

Is there a way to get "Some text" centered with respect to the outer container when there is enough space, but still having no overlap and `text-overflow: ellipsis` where there isn’t enough space?

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    padding: 2px;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    background: salmon;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: inline;
}

#container .text {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: center;
}

#container2 {
  display: grid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  background: hotpink;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: inline;
}

#container2 .text {
  justify-self: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <button>
        Left button
    </button>
    <div></div>
    <div class="text">
        Some text
    </div>
    <button>
        Right button with a long label
    </button>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <button>
        Left button
    </button>
    <div class="text">
        Some text
    </div>
    <button>
        Right button with a long label
    </button>
</div>
```